# Read and print out gifts

Tags: c++

The program shall include the following:

• A data type for storing a bag of gifts called `Gift_Bag_Type`. The data type should be able to
Store up to `15` gifts where each gift consists of a `string`.

• A `read_gifts` subroutine that has a `Gift_Bag_Type` parameter.
The subroutine should allow the user to enter up to `15` gifts to be stored in
parameters. The user ends the entry by entering "`DONE`" or by
enter `15` gifts.

• A `print_gifts_containing` subprogram that has a `Gift_Bag_Type` parameter `gift_bag` and a `character` parameter `letter`.

The subprogram should print
all gifts from `gift_bag` as the content sign facilitates. If no gifts are included
letter, "`none`" should be printed.

This is how it should look in the terminal:

```
Enter gifts in bag:
car
table
tv
acorn
tools
perfume
apple
DONE
Enter letter: e
Gifts containing e: table, perfume, apple
```

---

```
Enter gifts in bag:
DONE
Enter letter: a
Gifts containing a: none
```

I have a problem with making my other subprogram `print_gifts_containing`. I am thinking that I have to have a `for loop` and in the for loop I have a `if statement` but I don't really know how to execute it, and this is why I am asking this question here because I need assitance. Any help on how to complete this program?

NOTE that my `int main` should not be modified. Only my `subprograms`. I have only commented out one thing so that my programs compiles.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Gift_Bag_Type {
    vector<string> gifts;
};

//function to read gifts of input gift    
void read_gifts(Gift_Bag_Type & gift_bag) {
    string line;
        
    while ((line != "DONE") && (gift_bag.gifts.size() != 14)) {
        getline(cin, line);
        gift_bag.gifts.push_back(line);
    }  
}   

void print_gifts_containing (Gift_Bag_Type & gift_bag,
                             char const letter) {
    for (int i {}; i < gift_bag.gifts.size(); ++i) {
        //if-statement here
    }
}

int main() {
    Gift_Bag_Type gift_bag;
    char letter;

    cout << "Enter gifts in bag: " << endl;
    read_gifts(gift_bag);

    cout << "Enter letter: ";
    cin.get(letter);

    cout << "Gifts containing " << letter << ": ";
    //print_gifts_containing(gift_bag, letter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Break the problem into two parts, 1) a way to determine whether a given string contains a given character, and 2) a way to iterate over the vector of strings, performing the same operation on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) which has an overload that lets you find the first occurrence of a character in a string. Returns [`npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) if the character is not found.

A simple example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string foo = "hello";

    if (foo.find('e') != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "Found 'e'" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Additionally, when you iterate over your `vector` of strings, you're working too hard with your loop. C++ makes you work hard. Let it do the same for you when you can.

```
for (auto &s : gift_bag.gifts) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: It's the `print_gifts_containing subprogram` I need help with. The subprogram above is already done and finished. I just don't know what to write in my if-statement

Comment: That's what I've provided an answer for.